# Scheduled flows fail while accessing a single or a small set of Cash states

Tags: corda

What is the best approach for setting up a scenario where a single FungibleAsset (such as Cash.State) is issued, and a number of Scheduled flows are expected to consume it in varying amounts? While I understand the CashSelection implementations help create change, does it hold up for the scenario where multiple scheduled flows access the states at the same time? For example if a single Cash.State of 100 USD exists, and 50 ScheduledFlows were set up to each consume 2 USD, how can we avoid the situation where the Notary accidentally finds a State that has already been consumed?

Similar exceptions are seen when multiple flows are initiated back to back on a single node and targeting a single or a small set of states. I am running on open source corda 3.3 with Java version 1.8.0_131, over CentOS Linux.

Here is the exception I see:

> [WARN ] 2018-11-12T18:53:03,422Z [Node thread-2]
>   flow.[1ecbfdff-a0b6-4e0e-94d1-95c432822a02].run - Flow finished with
>   exception {} net.corda.core.flows.NotaryException: Unable to notarise
>   transaction2DFF6E03F64B7445A49191EDBEF70B3054BCF37F541A2FBA012A63FB8F5DEA53:
>   One or more input states have been used in another transaction    at
>   net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$Service.call(NotaryFlow.kt:149)
>   ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$Service.call(NotaryFlow.kt:133)
>   ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96)
>   [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]  at
>   net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44)
>   [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]  at
>   co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092)
>   [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]    at
>   co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788)
>   [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]    at
>   co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100)
>   [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]    at
>   co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91)
>   [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [?:1.8.0_192]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_192]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [?:1.8.0_192]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   [?:1.8.0_192]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [?:1.8.0_192]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [?:1.8.0_192]     at
>   net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62)
>   [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]

Comment: What exceptions are you receiving?

Comment: I've updated the post with the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The platform provides a soft-locking mechanism to prevent multiple flows from trying to spend the same `FungibleAsset` at the same time. In `NodeVaultService.tryLockFungibleStatesForSpending`, we have the following line:

```
softLockReserve(lockId, claimedStates.map { it.ref }.toNonEmptySet())
```

Can you update your question to show how you are retrieving the `FungibleAsset`s from the vault?

Comment: Thank you for that. I was simply retrieving the `FungibleAsset` instances using the regular vault query API. I will try out the lock based approach you suggest.